# change the name of multiple file for just a part of the filename

Tags: powershell, etl, file-rename

I have 50 files with file names having the format like:

```
SIGMOID 01012019 - 01082019.XLS
SIGMOID 01012019 - 01022019.XLS
```

I would like to change it to:

```
SIGMOID_01012019 - 01082019.XLS
SIGMOID_01012019 - 01022019.XLS
```

I want to update part of the filename and add an underscore instead of just the first blank space in the name.

Thank you

I tried writing a script in powershell

```
dir |
Where-Object { $_.name.Contains(" ") } |
Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace " ","_" }
```

but that updates every blank space.

Comment: Split the Name at only the first space and join with an underscore `gci 'SIGMOID *' |rename-item -newname {($_.Name -split ' ',2 -join '_')} -whatif`

Comment: I have a situation where even the name (SIGMOID) changes. Not all the files are from SIGMOID. What do you suggest I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have files like:

> ```
> SIGMOID 01012019 - 01082019.XLS
> SIGMOID 01012019 - 01022019.XLS
> SOMETHINGELSE    01012019 - 02022019.XLS
> YETANOTHERPREFIX 01012019 - 03022019.XLS
> ```

then the following code will rename them:

```
$sourceFolder = 'THE PATH OF THE ROOTFOLDER THAT STORES THE XLS FILES TO RENAME'   #'#  enter your rootpath here
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -File | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^\w+ +\d{8}.*\.xlsx?' } | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ($_.Name -replace '^(\w+) +(\d{8}.*\.xlsx?)', '$1_$2') -WhatIf
    }
```

to become

> ```
> SIGMOID_01012019 - 01082019.XLS
> SIGMOID_01012019 - 01022019.XLS
> SOMETHINGELSE_02012019 - 01022019.XLS
> YETANOTHERPREFIX_03012019 - 01022019.XLS
> ```

Note: remove the `-WhatIf` if you feel happy with the results

Regex details:

```
^           Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character)
(           Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \w       Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, etc.)
      +     Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)           
\           Match the character “ ” literally
   +        Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(           Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
   \d       Match a single digit 0..9
      {8}   Exactly 8 times
   .        Match any single character that is not a line break character
      *     Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   \.       Match the character “.” literally
   xls      Match the characters “xls” literally
   x        Match the character “x” literally
      ?     Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but perhaps exactly what you're looking for:

`Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace "SIGMOID ","SIGMOID_" }`

Comment: But I have names that change too. Even sigmoid changes. Do you have a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Turning my comment into an answer,

Split the Name at only the first space and join with an underscore
`'* *'` asures there is at least one space in the file name.

```
Get-ChildItem '* *' | 
     Rename-Item -NewName {($_.Name -split ' ',2 -join '_')} -Whatif
```

If the output looks OK, remove the `-WhatIf`

On successive runs this would change the `-` in your examples to `_-` etc.

To prevent that you'd need a `Where-Object` which excludes files with an underscore.

```
Get-ChildItem '* *' | 
  Where-Object Name -notmatch '^\S+_' |
     Rename-Item -NewName {($_.Name -split ' ',2 -join '_')} -Whatif
```

Answer (score 0):

Umm, how about replacing twice:

```
'SIGMOID 01012019 - 01082019.XLS' -replace ' ','_' -replace '_-_',' - '

SIGMOID_01012019 - 01082019.XLS
```

or (replace space with no dash on either side):

```
'SIGMOID 01012019 - 01082019.XLS' -replace '[^-] [^-]','_'

SIGMOI_1012019 - 01082019.XLS
```

Try out with rename-item -whatif ...